# Do operators of magic methods mean anything in Python?

Tags: python, class

So I'm learning how to use Python with Sololearn courses, and this is an example code they provided to teach us how magic method works.

```
class SpecialString:
    def __init__(self, cont):
        self.cont = cont

    def __gt__(self, other):
        for index in range(len(other.cont)+1):
            result = other.cont[:index] + ">" + self.cont
            result += ">" + other.cont[index:]
            print(result)

spam = SpecialString("spam")
eggs = SpecialString("eggs")
spam > eggs
```

The concept itself seems not that complicated, but the code makes it look complicated.

From the course, I learned that there are many built-in methods like `__add__` , `__lt__` , `__sub__` , etc, and that they are activated by operators. But when you look at the code, I feel like the meaning of operators doesn't necessarily lead to the function of magic method. Is it right that operators are just for activation of magic methods and don't mean anything, and we can just custom what will be done by using operators?

Comment: `gt` is short for "greater than" which is what `>` signifies. For example: `5 > 3` would result in `True`. Obviously, you can assign whatever logic you want, but the readers of your code would appreciate if you followed the spirit of the operator.

Comment: `spam > eggs` - while valid - mostly useless.  Usually you would want to use it in `if`(or similar) or assign its result to a variable.

Comment: What do you mean by `the meaning of operators doesn't necessarily lead to the function of magic method`? Are you saying that when you execute `spam > eggs` that it doesn't seem to call the `__gt__` method?

Comment: @PM77-1 In this particular example, using `spam > eggs` in an `if` would be pointless since `__gt__()` has no explicit return and returns `None` by default.

Comment: @Code They're saying that it seems strange that this `__gt__` method doesn't do a comparison (which IMHO is totally justified; you should have a very good justification for making a magic method's behaviour not match its name, like [`Path / Path`](//docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use) for example).

Comment: @Code That's exactly what PM's saying: this method doesn't have a result (`return`), which makes it mostly useless. Personally, I wouldn't use a magic method for this.

Comment: What I mean by that is, as far as I know, operators have their owns meanings such as that * means multiplication and / means division but it seems like operators used for activation of magic methods don't have any built-in function related to their original function. For example, if I used * to activate a magic method in class, can't I just modify it so that it does totally different function from the original function of *?

Comment: @NoelKim `*` means multiplication (at least when you use it as `2 * 3`) because there is a magic method `int.__mul__` that multiplies two integers. The meaning matches our expectation here because the python developers made it that way. It is good practice to use magic methods in a way that the operator matches the user's expectation, but this isn't enforced by the language at all.

Answer (score 2):

Operator overloading allows you to define any meaning you want to operators. For example, Pandas and NumPy redefine the bitwise `&` and `|` operators as element-wise logical operators on their collections. And `list1 += list2` is equivalent to `list1.extend(list2)` (so it updates the target list in place) rather than `list1 = list1 + list` (which creates a new list and reassigns the variable).

However, you sometimes need to be careful. When there are related operators, the default implementations may make assumptions about the relationship. For instance, the default implementation of the `>=` operator might assume that

```
x >= y
```

is equivalent to

```
not (x < y)
```

If you overload one but not the other, you might get inconsistent results.

C++ has taken operator overloading to an extreme in the way it uses `<<` and `>>` as I/O operators when the first argument is a stream. This is far removed from their default meaning as bit-shift operators. But bit-shift makes little sense for streams, and they have mnemonic value because they look like arrows that point in the direction that data is moving with respect to the stream and variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can write any logic we want in the magic methods. This means you can define the operator to mean anything you want. However, you should be careful. Only use these magic methods when the operation and logic you want to perform makes sense with the operator associated with the magic method. Most of the time you would be better off defining a regular method so that you can meaningfully name it to describe what it is doing.